# CopyFromRecordset taking too much time

Tags: excel, vba

I am running below one VBA code and in that `CopyFromRecordset` is being called multiple time and taking too much time for execution.

Is there any way to reduce execution time?

```
DBPath = ThisWorkbook.FullName
Sconnect = "Provider=MSDASQL.1;DSN=Excel Files;DBQ=" & DBPath & ";HDR=Yes';"
con.Open Sconnect
SQLQuery = "Select * from [ALM_Scenario_Dump$] where Scenario_Name='" & Scenario_Na & "'"
mrs.Open SQLQuery, con
               ThisWorkbook.Sheets("ALM_Scenario_Detailed_Temp").Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset mrs
mrs.Close
con.Close
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have already, you can add these before copying over the recordset:

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.Calculation = xlManual
```

Then turn them back to normal after the data is copied over.

The only other way I can think of for copying over the recordset data would be to loop through all of the fields in the recordset but I can't imagine this being any faster.

Please also see SwiftJr's answer on: [VBA: Querying Access with Excel. Why so slow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1574213/vba-querying-access-with-excel-why-so-slow)

Maybe you can set your cursor location with `CursorLocation = adUseClient` on your connection as the answer notes

Comment: I tried did but no change in execution time for CopyFromRecordset

Comment: Did you try the `CursorLocation = adUseClient` part? @pavanjangid

Comment: @pavanjangid Are you calling `con.Close` after each query? You can leave the connection open between queries and call `con.Close` when you are done.